# How to connect node.js backend to NGINX reverse proxy server

Tags: nginx, node.js

I know I'm close but I can't seem to connect my `node.js` app to my `NGINX` reverse proxy.  My node app works locally and my config file tests ok.  It doesn't connect after it's been uploaded to Digital Ocean.

The error is **502 Bad Gateway**.

Something is missing and after a couple of hours of googling and testing I still can't find the problem.  Thanks so much for any help in advance!

These are the relevant lines from my `nginx.conf` file.

```js
 server {
        listen        80;
        listen        [::]:80;
        server_name   myDomainName.com;
        root          /www/html;

        location / {
             index       index.html;
        }

        location /proxytest {
            proxy_pass "http://www.myDomainName.com:8080";
        }

    }
```

This is my `node.js` test app.

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 8080');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all running a single instance, then typically Nginx wants to talk to a local nodejs service running on port 8080, and so localhost would be more usual than `www.myDomainName.com`

This would normally be something like

```
 location /proxytest {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
```

Whatever you set the proxy_pass value to, you should check that address is available from the nginx box command line.

```
# curl -I  http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 02:23:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Also you can check the error log on nginx to see if it reported anything funny.

```
vi /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

## Other things to try

If you are on an selinux distribution (CentOS, Fedora, RHEL...) try disabling selinux and try the request again

```
 # setenforce Permissive
 setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tom!  I used `curl -I  http://localhost:8080` and it returned `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.  So for my next step I typed `ps -aef` and my node server was running.  I checked SELinux and my server is set to `httpd_sys_content_t` just like the rest of the files in my folder.  DAC looks fine too.  If the server returns 404 what should I check?

Comment: are you sure its the node app listening on 8080 and not something else? I started that app on my box.. `$ node ~/Downloads/test1.js \n Server is up on port 8080`

Comment: and the output is `$ curl -I http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
ETag: W/"c-Lve95gjOVATpfV8EL5X4nxwjKHE"
Date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 16:41:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: I rebooted the server.  Oddly enough when I used `ps -aef | grep 8080` it returns `first    10388 10343  0 09:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 8080`  But server.js is running.

Comment: `ps -aef | grep node` returns `first    10381 10343  0 09:54 pts/0    00:00:00 node server.js` and `first    10391 10343  0 09:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto node`